# How to seed data from crawling in Magento application database?

Tags: database, magento, web-crawler, seeding

I am building an eCommerce website. I am new to Magento as well.

I am required to crawl data from a website and seed the same data in my upcoming website. How to save the data in tables. How to organize the data?

Edit
For me the major challenge is database structure. I saw database table. And the information is spread-ed over the tables. I can put data in database by any technology, BUT how to ensure, right data going in right column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list items from magento database by Magento SOAP API, or by the programming way. Those data you can set to array and save to your new database.

You can make script for export data as XML as well.

Last way is to export them by Magento Admin.

Priority will be, i think, the simplest way, you saving data to your new system.

Comment: For me the major challenge is database structure. I saw database table. And the information is spread-ed over the tables. I can put data in database by any technology, BUT how to ensure, right data should do in right column?

Comment: I mean my answer this way: magento have a LOT of tables to handle product database. Is not wise to call items directly from database.

Comment: You can use programming way, direct commands to get all the products and all the values of products only by calling it on magento. for example: GetSku(), GetName(), and you do not need to care about magento tables or future uploads.
Make script, call Magento Api and call all items, use foreach to save to an array ordered by SKU, after that you can call all tiems simple by $myitems["sku"]["color"]...there is the script which you can change to list items in catalog and return MySQL INSERT to your system.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922563/exporting-order-details-magento/19925110#19925110